# Is there a way to .type/.fill and .press in a single sentence on Playwright?

Tags: typescript, playwright

Just as the title implies I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify this into only one line:

```
await configWebdoxPage.profileSelector.click()
await configWebdoxPage.profileSelector.type(userData.userProfile)    
await configWebdoxPage.profileSelector.press('Enter')
```

or another example:

```
await configWebdoxPage.groupSelector.type('QA')
await configWebdoxPage.groupSelector.press('Enter')
```

Sorry for the noobish question but I just started using Playwright yesterday and I haven't been able to find anything regarding this

Thanks in advance!
Kind Regards

Comment: You want something like actions in selenium, but 95% sure they do not exist in playwright.Try to see implementation of drag and drop or hover methods in playwright.If they are using 3 lines, just use 3 lines.:-)

Comment: `page.fill()` already does all that selector searching, actionability checking, element focusing, input filling and input triggering. See this [link](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-fill)

Comment: @kali but how would that work out when the element you want to interact with is a react selector where you want to type and select the corresponding input-search result?

When using page.fill I'm getting:
`locator.fill: Error: Element is not an <input>, <textarea> or [contenteditable] element`

Comment: Well, if you're not dealing with this kind of Locator what the error says (so not a content editable element), I guess it is yet not possible to do it in Playwright. Maybe in the next releases.